# which table to store data like simple product in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, database, custom-attributes, simple-product

which database table to store data like simple product in Magento 2 and its all related info. like custom attribute?

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here some information

`catalog_product_entity_varchar`  = Title & Description & URL

`catalog_product_entity_decimal`    =  Product Price

`catalog_category_product`   =  Assign Product to Category

`cataloginventory_stock_item` = For Inventory Quantity

`catalog_url_rewrite_product_category` = For URL Rewrite

`eav_attribute`  = which store ALL Attributes

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Just that not any other table @Rakesh

Comment: okk like 6 tables to see product in frontend and backend @Rakesh

Comment: @Prits here i have main table described, also other many table like:`catalog_product_website`(website),`catalog_product_entity_decimal`(price),`catalog_product_entity_int` (visibility) also other many table

Comment: Actually i want all tables when a product is created how many tables are there to insert data @Rakesh
will you please tell me all the table name or any post link which have all table name.

Comment: @Prits here all information please look at: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140227/68695

Comment: Thanks for the info @Rakesh

Comment: Done will you please help me with this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/322575/why-success-message-is-not-shown-on-mail-sent-in-magento-2 @Rakesh